# Can't Center Video.js Video in Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Ok, I have tried just about everything I can think of margin:0 auto; margin-left:auto; margin-right auto. I have tried the 'center' tag in bootstrap.  text-center does not affect the content. I've tried it in probably all level of the divs and elements. I can not seem to get the dang thing centered. Using Video.js for the video on Bootstrap 3 using MVC5.

HTML

For some reason part of the code won't render, so here is a image of the top portion that is not visible.

[html_snip http://www.educatetograduateinc.com/Content/img/E2G_Html_Snip.jpg](http://www.educatetograduateinc.com/Content/img/E2G_Html_Snip.jpg)

WORD FROM THE STREET

```
        <div class="br-hr type_short"> <span class="br-hr-h">
                    <i class="icon-pencil"></i>
                </span>

        </div>
        <div class="carousel carousel-fade slide carousel-featuredwork center" id="carousel-testimonials" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carousel-testimonials" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-testimonials" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-testimonials" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner" style="margin-top:-20px;">
                <div class="item active" style="overflow:visible;padding:0 0 0 0;">
                    <div class="videoUiWrapper thumbnail">
                        <video width="640" height="480" id="demo1" poster="http://educatetograduateinc.com/Content/img/E2G_Video_poster.jpg">
                            <source src="http://educatetograduateinc.com/Content/video/E2G_Video_Debt_rev2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                                <source src="http://educatetograduateinc.com/Content/video/E2G_Video_Debt_rev2.ogv" type="video/ogg">
                                    <source src="http://educatetograduateinc.com/Content/video/E2G_Video_Debt_rev2.webm" type='video/webm' />Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item" style="overflow:visible;padding:0 0 0 0;">
                    <div class="videoUiWrapper thumbnail">
                        <video width="640" height="480" id="demo2" poster="http://educatetograduateinc.com/Content/img/E2G_Video_poster.jpg">
                            <source src="http://educatetograduateinc.com/Content/video/E2G_Video_Lotto_rev2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                                <source src="http://educatetograduateinc.com/Content/video/E2G_Video_Lotto_rev2.ogv" type="video/ogg">
                                    <source src="http://educatetograduateinc.com/Content/video/E2G_Video_Lotto_rev2.webm" type='video/webm' />Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item" style="overflow:visible;padding:0 0 0 0;">
                    <div class="videoUiWrapper thumbnail">
                        <video width="640" height="480" id="demo3" poster="http://educatetograduateinc.com/Content/img/E2G_Video_poster.jpg">
                            <source src="http://educatetograduateinc.com/Content/video/E2G_Video_Lawyer_rev4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                                <source src="http://educatetograduateinc.com/Content/video/E2G_Video_Lawyer_rev4.ogv" type="video/ogg">
                                    <source src="http://educatetograduateinc.com/Content/video/E2G_Video_Lawyer_rev4.webm" type='video/webm' />Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.carousel-inner -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a picture of the carousel in the wild..

[html_snip http://www.educatetograduateinc.com/Content/img/E2G_WebShot.jpg](http://www.educatetograduateinc.com/Content/img/E2G_WebShot.jpg)

I also have a fiddle...  http://jsfiddle.net/6B59S/12/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Put width=100% for video tag http://jsfiddle.net/st88F/

```
           <video width="100%" height="480" id="demo1" ....
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work in the actual app. See here, I uploaded your edit as well as the below one. http://educatetograduateinc.com/

Comment: change the default css :.videoUiWrapper.thumbnail {
float: left;
} become: .videoUiWrapper.thumbnail {
float: none;
}

Answer (score 0):

There was a conflict between video.js and bootstrap carousel. Thanks all for your help.